# datediff not returning what I'm expecting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

Anyone know why the following is returning `8`?  I'm expecting 8 hours 30 minutes, or 8.5?

```
declare @start_day datetime;
declare @end_day datetime;
declare @start_time datetime;
declare @end_time datetime;

set @start_day = '2014-06-18';
set @end_day = '2014-06-18';
set @start_time = '09:00';
set @end_time = '17:30';

print datediff(hour,@start_day + @start_time, @end_day + @end_time);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, CAST your DATEDIFF of the minutes to float then divide by 60 to get the hours.

```
declare @start_day datetime;
declare @end_day datetime;
declare @start_time datetime;
declare @end_time datetime;

set dateformat ymd

set @start_day = '2014-06-18';
set @end_day = '2014-06-18';
set @start_time = '09:00';
set @end_time = '17:30';

print cast(datediff(minute,@start_day + @start_time, @end_day + @end_time) as float) / 60;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
print cast(datediff(mi,@start_day + @start_time, @end_day + @end_time) 
           as decimal(10,2))/60;
```

Answer (score 0):

it returns the number of fully elapsed hours. 
if you want to have 8.5 return minutes and then divide by 60.0.

Comment: `print datediff(minute,@start_day + @start_time, @end_day + @end_time);` give me `510`, but this `print datediff(minute,@start_day + @start_time, @end_day + @end_time)/60;` still gives me `8`...

Answer (score 0):

You have `hour` as a datepart, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) states:

> **DATEDIFF**
>
> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
> boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

Answer (score 0):

The The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates. And its syntax is

```
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
```

Here in datepart you are mentioning **hour** so thats why it is printing only hours part